# What is meant by the values returned by cv2.HoughLinesP()?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, houghlines

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

I am using this code to detect line in a PNG image, and the function returns a numpy array :

```
array([[[124, 235, 393, 235]],

       [[124, 233, 393, 233]]])
```

I wanted to know what these values mean in order to get the length and direction of the line detected.

*The image used contains only one horizontal line.

Comment: The openCV documentation contains enough information to answer your question - https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

Comment: OK got it...1st one is for starting point and 3rd is for end point

Comment: but in case of many lines the returned array is like : 
array([[[169, 270, 357, 270]],

       [[169, 268, 357, 268]],

       [[357, 267, 357, 101]],

       [[359, 268, 359, 102]],

       [[358, 100, 465, 100]],

       [[360, 102, 465, 102]]])

But how to identify which one is for which line ?

Comment: What do you mean by "which one is for which line"?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cv2.HoughLinesP) is quite explicit... ` Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a 4-element vector  (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) , where  (x_1,y_1) and  (x_2, y_2) are the ending points of each detected line segment.` the only difference is that in python is a list. but basically it is a list of line segments. Sometimes you may get almost the same line (look the first 2 in your comment) they are both one next to each other, just that one is 2 pixels higher, probably a thick line have this effect